# How can I reproduce the hash derivation of promtail in order to query for obfuscated data?

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I'm using a log aggregation setup where sensitive data that is prepared for submission to *loki* is obfuscated with [Promtail's Hash filter](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/promtail/stages/template/#hash-and-sha2hash) under consideration of a salt value.

I want to dispatch a query with *Grafana* to look for a specific value that would have been transformed in that way. Therefore I have to calculate what Promtail would derive from that value.

I assume I could reproduce the result on a current Ubuntu Desktop OS like this:

```
$ echo "Value of interest" | shasum -a 256 -
```

But how would I have to bring the salt value into the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen [here](https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/clients/pkg/logentry/stages/template.go#L39-L46) functions `Hash` and `Sha2Hash` both simply invoke hashing functions over simple concatenation of salt and input value:

```golang
"Hash": func(salt string, input string) string {
    hash := sha3.Sum256([]byte(salt + input))
    return hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])
},
"Sha2Hash": func(salt string, input string) string {
    hash := sha256.Sum256([]byte(salt + input))
    return hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])
},
```

Note that [the documentation proposes a configuration where value and salt are swapped](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/7014), which must be considered if you followed it. Also, it must be ensured that no newline character is added when using `echo`.
Thus, using [rhash](https://rhash.sourceforge.io/) in this example, the hash can be derived with:

```bash
echo -n "Value of interest""salt" | rhash --sha3-256 -
```

The "inner" consecutive quote characters only serve clarity, they could be omitted.